# Is it okay to omit Open Graph and Twitter tags for social network cards and SEO?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, open-graph-protocol, twitter-card

My pages already have good html meta tags like `title` and `description` for Google SEO. I also added `og:title`, `og:description`, `twitter:title`, `twitter:description` and other meta tags, but I found in most cases `og:title`/`twitter:title` are the same as `title`, and `description` is also very redundant. So, can I omit some redundant meta tags for smaller page size, and not expect any negative impact?

```
<title>short title here</title>
<meta name="description" content="long description" />
<!-- section of og:... meta headers -->
<meta property="og:title" content="short title here" />
<meta property="og:description" content="long description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="..." />
<!-- section of twitter:... meta headers -->
<meta property="twitter:title" content="short title here" />
<meta property="twitter:description" content="long description" />
```

The `og:url` tag (for Facebook) also looks redundant to `<link rel="canonical" href="..." >` (for Google).

Can I omit the redundant ones, and keep only the unique ones not provided by another group, like this twitter card?

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
```

So, will facebook/twitter default to using the page's title/description tags when og:title/og:description are missing? And not penalize the content?

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: In 17 years of owning a web dev company, I have never used the og: and twitter stuff for any of the companies we worked for and all were on the front page of search results for always. Now, if you need search results on Facebook and Twitter exclusively, that might be helpful.

Comment: @rob XHTML requires that all tags (including meta tags) have closing tags or self close with by ending with `/>`.  It is not wrong to self close meta tags in other HTML variants.   Documentation often includes the self closing slashes for widest compatibility that includes XHTML.   These days I would never recommend somebody use XHTML over HTML5, so I'm not sure how much benefit that compatibility in documentation provides.

Comment: @rob the `og:` and `twitter:` tags are not useful for any search, but for your URLs are shared on social media sites.  They control how the preview of your page looks when shared.   It is worth paying attention to them if you are trying to get traction in social media.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I would almost bet he is not using XHTML. If he is, he has far more serious issues with his markup. In addition, NO documentation by the W3C or WHATWG will give you ANY such example or suggestion to use a closing slash in the history of HTML even today and I defy anyone to find such a thing. While the closing slash is allowed, it is unspecified anywhere as a requirement or need, it does nothing, it has no meaning and browsers are instructed to ignore it. So doing so is pointless, worthless, a waste of effort and bandwidth. Why anyone would do such  thing is bizarre at best.

Comment: As for the usage for Facebook and Twitter, I already said that it could be useful for those.

Comment: What would be the benefit of removing these tags? They're not hurting you, but they're potentially helping you if you post a link to your site on social media. I don't feel like they're redundant because they _are_ used for different purposes.

Answer (score 3):

### Twitter-specific Tags

The twitter-specific title and description meta tags are redundant if they are identical to your `og` tags, so you can leave them out.

If you omit `twitter:title`, Twitter will fallback to your `og:title` tag.

If you omit `twitter:description`, Twitter will fallback to your `og:description` tag.

If you don't include an `og:type` tag then you will want to include a `twitter:card` type. But if you do include `og:type`, then even `twitter:card` "may" not be needed, though personally I would still include it just to be sure. According to the [twitter card markup docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/markup):

> If an og:type, og:title and og:description exist in the markup but twitter:card is absent, then a summary card may be rendered.

In any case, the best way to check the validity of your card is to use [Twitter's Card Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) tool. Then you can be sure that your tags are set up properly to show cards.

### Title and Description Tags

I am not certain whether Twitter or Facebook fall back to the `title` and `description` tags if `og:title`, `twitter:title`, `og:description` or `twitter:description` are not present, but I couldn't find any indication in their documentation that they do. Someone would have to test this on a live website with the Twitter Card Validator and [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

### Rel canonical and og:url tags

I found no evidence in Facebook's documentation that they pay attention to `rel canonical`, so I recommend you continue to use both `rel canonical` and `og:url`.

Comment: LinkedIn uses Open Graph as well

Answer (score 2):

The only negative impact you'll see *potentially* would be in engagement on social media due to the snippet being smaller/less "in your face" on social media: Likes, Click Through Rate.

Facebook *should* fall back to the "rawest" form of metadata that your document provides - Its crawler is perfectly capable of it, however, it doesn't *prefer* it.

I say it's up to you!

In my book, removing these tags is totally fine! I can certainly respect a desire for clean code, but I mean we're talking about a few extra bytes.  From an SEO perspective, I'm not concerned with it at all.

You certainly won't be punished by Google - they care more about the semantics that your structured data creates...or the AMP markup you provide.

You stated that:

> The og:url tag (for Facebook) also looks redundant to  (for Google).

I wouldn't say that (or any of the others) are *redundant*; `og:url` is more like "canonical" in the *preferred language* (in this case, Facebook's). Basically, I see it like Apple's "Thunderbolt" charger...because USB-C just wasn't *extra* enough.

Twitter, Pinterest, and LinkedIn also respect Open Graph Protocol. If I'm not mistaken, Google+ *did* too (RIP).

If you wanted to *accommodate* social media structured data formats, this would be the minimum required:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="example title">
<meta property="og:description" content="a fun example description that's fun">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

Twitter allows the substitution of Open Graph `<meta>` tags for its own - so *those* are certainly redundant.